# Design of genetic algorithm which would allow TDD

Tags: java, beginner, unit-testing, genetic-algorithm

I'm implementing genetic algorithm in Java and I want to learn TDD with this project.

Currently I have this code:

```
package geneticAlgoritm;

import geneticAlgoritm.randomNumbers.IRandomGenerator;
import geneticAlgoritm.randomNumbers.RandomGenerator;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;

import java.util.List; 

public class Population {
    @NonNull private IRandomGenerator generator = new RandomGenerator();

    @Getter
    @NonNull
    private List<Chromosome> population;

    @NonNull final IFitnessCalculator calculator;

    public Population(int n, IFitnessCalculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
        this.population = generatePopulation(n);
    }

    int nextGeneration() {

    }

    private List<Chromosome> generatePopulation(int n) {
        return null;
    }

    private Chromosome mutate(Chromosome chromosome, double probability) {
        return null;
    }

    private Chromosome crossover(Chromosome first, Chromosome second, double probability) {
        return null;
    }

    private List<Chromosome> pickBestOfPopulation(int n) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have Chromosome class, which is wrapper for byte[] array and fitness of that array.

`nextGeneration` generates new population with better traits. How I can change design to allow testing crossover, mutate etc functions?

`nextGeneration` is really inconvenient to test for all functionalities, especially with some randomness in each (I'm using custom interface to remove it).

Comment: "IRandomGenerator" generator should be passed in the constructor.
Add the test class with some cases. Right now, I don't know what nextGeneration will do. That's a good way to start with TDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already written the API of your implementation. Being strict: That's not how tdd works.

1. Write *one* failing test
2. Make the test pass
3. Refactor

Your test case should not only test your implementation, but also *document the behaviour* of your implementation - *without* having written the implementation. And if you're at the first point, your test case describes the *expected behaviour* of your implementation. And it guides the design of your implementation.

And what's very important, too: *Know when to stop*. If you have code which is not covered by your test cases - and should be covered by a test case - at the end of an iteration, you did it wrong.

And in my opinion: A code review does help, but not too much. Because with tdd, an application *grows iteration by iteration*. And the thoughts which have to be thought during those steps have to be learned and practiced.

Comment: @Jump3r It's possible the confusion was between the terms "TDD" and "Unit testing". These are related concepts but not synonymous

Comment: I was just thinking about this concept as: 1. create needed methods stubs, 2. create tests to make specify behaviour, 3. implement to pass tests.